# Function to reference class variable in Python

Tags: python, function, class, python-2.7, pywin32

I have a program that uses python for windows extensions to control the mouse.
I'm trying to make a function that calls a class variable (I think that's what they're called).

Anyways the code looks like this:

```
class Mouse:

    def move_mouse(self, pos):
        """move the mouse to the specified coordinates"""
        (x, y) = pos
        old_pos = self.get_position()
        x =  x if (x != -1) else old_pos[0]
        y =  y if (y != -1) else old_pos[1]
        self._do_event(self.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE + self.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, x, y, 0, 0)
```

It's called like this:

```
mouse = Mouse();
position = (3,5); #some coordinate (where the mouse is on the screen)
mouse.move_mouse(position);
```

I'm wondering if I can create a function to make it easier to call the  move_mouse() function. Can I get it to call a position that I have previously defined? Like can I create something that would work like this:

```
positions = {"0": (123,432), "1": (312,123)}

def move(x);
    mouse.move(positions[str(x)]);

>>>move(0)
```

And the function should proceed to move to the first entry in the positions dictionary.

I can't stop it from getting an error when I run it. Does anybody know why it doesn't work?

Comment: *"an error"* - what error? You seem to have some errant semi-colons; could that be it?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be a *class attribute* of pre-defined positions, then when `Mouse.move_mouse` is called it either tries to retrieve the `pos` from that dictionary, assuming it's a key, or uses it directly if it isn't a key:

```
class Mouse:

    POSITIONS = {'home': (0, 0), ...}

    def move_mouse(self, pos):
        """move the mouse to the specified coordinates"""
        x, y = self.POSITIONS.get(pos, pos)
        ...
```

Now both `mouse.move_mouse('home')` and `mouse.move_mouse((0, 0))` would have the same effect.